# Stop recursive function on viewDidUnload

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a recursive function that plays a UIView animation continuously (if there is a better way to do this, please let me know):

```
-(void)playAnimationRecursive
{
    [appDelegate commenceFishAnimation];
    [animationView addSubview:appDelegate.fishAnimationImageView];
    animationView.alpha=0.5;

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:14.0 target:self selector:@selector(playAnimationRecursive) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}
```

and not sure if this is neccessary, but here's the appDelegate commenceFishAnimationMethod:

```
        upperFish=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:upperFishImage];
        bigFish=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:bigFishImage];
        shark=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:sharkImage];
        groupFish=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:groupFishImage];
        fish1=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:fish1Image];
        fishAnimationImageView=[[[UIImageView alloc] init] retain];

        //set the initial position of each fish to be out of frame
        upperFish.frame=CGRectMake(-50, 150, 119/2, 93/2); //moves east
        bigFish.frame=CGRectMake(-280, 340, 251/2, 137/2); //moves east
        shark.frame=CGRectMake(-100, 390, 164/2, 52/2); //moves east
        groupFish.frame=CGRectMake(500, 320, 155/2, 89/2); //moves west
        fish1.frame=CGRectMake(370, 280, 155/2, 89/2); //moves west

        //add fishes to current view
        [fishAnimationImageView addSubview:upperFish];
        [fishAnimationImageView addSubview:bigFish];
        [fishAnimationImageView addSubview:shark];
        [fishAnimationImageView addSubview:groupFish];
        [fishAnimationImageView addSubview:fish1];

        //animate the position of each fish view
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:10.0];
        [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear];
        upperFish.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(150, -200);
        bigFish.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(600, 0);
        shark.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(550, 0);
        groupFish.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-600, 0);
        fish1.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-550, 0);

        [UIView commitAnimations];
        [fishAnimationImageView release];
        [upperFish release];
        [bigFish release];
        [shark release];
        [groupFish release];
        [fish1 release];  
}
```

So what happens is that every view I have plays this animation in the BG, so if I'm on view A, then it calls the recursive function and plays the animation continuously. If I move to view B, then it calls the recursive function also and plays the animation continuously. However, I'm getting memory warning level 2, and I'm thinking maybe it's because view A is still calling the recursive method? If that is the reason, then how would I stop the recursive method on unload? Or is that not my problem?

EDIT:

Here's my code now (animation doesn't loop)

```
-(void)commenceFishAnimation
{
    UIImageView *newImageView=[[UIImageView alloc] init];
    self.fishAnimationImageView=newImageView;

    upperFish=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:upperFishImage];
    bigFish=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:bigFishImage];
    shark=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:sharkImage];
    groupFish=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:groupFishImage];
    fish1=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:fish1Image];

    //set the initial position of each fish to be out of frame
    upperFish.frame=CGRectMake(-50, 150, 119/2, 93/2); //moves east
    bigFish.frame=CGRectMake(-280, 340, 251/2, 137/2); //moves east
    shark.frame=CGRectMake(-100, 390, 164/2, 52/2); //moves east
    groupFish.frame=CGRectMake(500, 320, 155/2, 89/2); //moves west
    fish1.frame=CGRectMake(370, 280, 155/2, 89/2); //moves west

    //add fishes to current view
    [fishAnimationImageView addSubview:upperFish];
    [fishAnimationImageView addSubview:bigFish];
    [fishAnimationImageView addSubview:shark];
    [fishAnimationImageView addSubview:groupFish];
    [fishAnimationImageView addSubview:fish1];

    //animate the position of each fish view
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:10.0];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear];
    upperFish.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(150, -200);
    bigFish.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(600, 0);
    shark.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(550, 0);
    groupFish.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-600, 0);
    fish1.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-550, 0);

    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(commenceFishAnimation)];
    [UIView commitAnimations]; 

    [fishAnimationImageView release];
    [upperFish release];
    [bigFish release];
    [shark release];
    [groupFish release];
    [fish1 release];
    //[newImageView release]; //if I release it, then my animation doesn't play for some reason
}
```

Then in some other class in the viewDidLoad method, I do this:

```
[appDelegate commenceFishAnimation];
[animationView addSubview:appDelegate.fishAnimationImageView];
```

But the animation only plays once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not the best way chaining animations, use this instead:

```
    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(playAnimation)];
```

That will chain your animations in an infinite loop.

But also note that in your method `playAnimationRecursive` you are adding subviews and scheduling a `NSTimer` every 14 seconds without releasing them. Thats a really bad idea.

To sum up: forget about recursion and use the method above.

**EDIT:** I forgot to mention that you have to assign the delegate of the animation:

```
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];  //self or whatever implements playAnimation selector
```

Comment: And you can use `[UIView setAnimationDelay:4.0]` to get the 4 second pause between repeats you had with your method.

Comment: I tried what you recommended but for some reason the animation does not loop-it only plays once. I have  `[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(commenceFishAnimation)];` at the end of my `commenceFishAnimation` method.

Comment: I forgot to mention that you have to assign the animation's delegate. [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self] Also be sure you're calling it before calling    [UIView commitAnimations];

Comment: Ok, first you shouldn't create a new fishAnimationImageView at the beginning of the method if you're going to call it each iteration. I recommend you to try setAnimationRepeatCount: and set a very very high value (forget about using didStopSelector when using this).

Comment: But this still doesn't solve my problem. My animation doesn't repeat..I'm thinking maybe it has something to do with my views and the way I'm handling memory, but I don't know what

Comment: Nm actually I got it to work..not sure what the problem was I just moved up a few lines and it worked..thanks!

Comment: Just by what you said, but I think I had some stuff written in the wrong place. Now the only thing that doesn't work is the delay between animation. I'm using [UIView setAnimationDelay:4.0] but it only delays before the first time, but after that it doesn't delay and just plays..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3638/discussion-between-ender-and-mohabitar)

Answer (score 1):

I see a few red flags that suggest you don't have a good understanding of reference counting in Objective C.

```
[[[UIImageView alloc] init] retain];
```

Never do that. `alloc` already gives you a reference count of 1. You don't need to retain it also.

```
fishAnimationImageView=[[[UIImageView alloc] init] retain];
```

Uh-oh, what happened to the previous object referenced by fishAnimationImageView? It is still retained, but nobody has a reference to it. Leak!

```
[fishAnimationImageView release];
```

Technically correct, since you double-retained it before, but you should normally not release that object because it is (I assume) an instance variable of your app delegate.

Here is what you should do.

```
UIImageView *newFishAnimationImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
// retain count = 1
self.fishAnimationImageView = newFishAnimationView;
// retain count = 2
// old value retain count = 0
// assuming a typical property declaration as retain, and setter made by @synthesize
[newFishAnimationView release];
// retain count = 1; not owned locally, but owned by your app delegate
```

Referring to things by their properties typically gets you the correct reference counting behavior. Follow that, and the rule of releasing anything you alloc, and there aren't many cases where you will go wrong.

You should probably review the documentation on reference counting.

Also, try out Product > Profile in XCode, and pick Leaks. It can tell you if you have memory leaks and where they are.